# How to assure that some processing is made in single instances

Tags: java, spring, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, multiple-instances

Let's assume that I want to call some processing on set of students.

Let's say we've got students `S = [ s1, s2, ..., s10 ]`
and three service instances `I = [ i1, i2, i3 ]`.

I want to make sure that instance `i1` is processing, as an example, `[ s1, s2, s4 ]`, whereas `i2` is processing `[ s3, s5 ]` etc.

Is it doable in Zookeeper or I shall focus on different tool?